# Append a value into a class array

Tags: python, arrays, class

I have a very basic question. I need to fill an array in a loop that was declared in a class. A simplified code is something like:

```
class Arr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = []

var = Arr
for x in xrange(0, 3):
    var.test.append(1)
```

This code always return "class Arr has no attribute 'test'", but I don't see the reason. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create an *instance* of the class using `var = Arr()`.

If you do just `var = Arr`, then `var` is a reference to the class `Arr` itself, not an instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an `Arr` instance instead of manipulating the class itself like others mentioned.

But it is also considered a good practice not to manipulate internal instance members from the outside. You should have a method that initializes `test` array.:

```
class Arr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = []

    def initialize(self, cnt):
        for i in range(cnt):
            self.test.append( 1 )
```

Plus you might also consider using new-style python classes:

```
class Arr(object):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Instance**

Please change to

```
class Arr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = []

var = Arr()
for x in xrange(0, 3):
    var.test.append(1)
```

You must create an instance of Arr Class, to assign values to the list inside the class

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing "class Arr has no attribute 'test'" because the class hasn't. An instance would have the attribute though. In order make it an attribute of the class you would have to... well, make it an attribute of the class.

```
class Arr(object):
    test = []

var = Arr
for x in xrange(0, 3):
    var.test.append(1)

print Arr.test
```